# Limit in edge points of domain

Tags: limits, functions

For calculus I was given some relatively easy problems to make. Among others, I was asked to give the intervals where this (http://puu.sh/kmO0H/a4bbac5628.jpg) function was differentiable. Of course the breaks in the middle are not included in these intervals, but the answer book says the edge points are not included either.

Why is this? Is it not true that the limit from the right / left exists for the edge points and is equal to the value of the function so it is continuous there, also making it differentiable since df/dx exists? Does a limit only exist if both the left and right limit exist and are equal?

Comment: Can you give your course's definition of "differentiable"? Mine reads "Let $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. $f$ is differentiable at $x \in (a, b)$ iff (the correct limit exists)." That is, from my course it's not even meaningful to ask whether $f$ is differentiable at $a$: the property of differentiability is not defined there.

Comment: http://puu.sh/kmQpU/9d6a835d23.jpg

Comment: That is still unclear. If we define $f: \mathbb{R} \setminus \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, does the limit of $f(x)$ exist as $x \to 0$?